# TypeError: unhashable type: 'OptimizeResult' while Parallel processing

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run Parallel programming in python using [pp package](http://www.parallelpython.com/), but it is running through some iterations and then, throwing an error :

Please help

```
ppservers = ()

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  ncpus = int(sys.argv[1])
  # Creates jobserver with ncpus workers
  job_server = pp.Server(ncpus, ppservers=ppservers)
else:
  # Creates jobserver with automatically detected number of workers
  job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers)

print "Starting pp with", job_server.get_ncpus(), "workers"


start_time = ti.time()

jobs = []
for new_data_set in many_isotopomer_data:
  jobs.append(job_server.submit(optimzation(ob.objective, input_dict, method ='SLSQP', args=(system_ode, params_val_dict, initial_cond, time, new_data_set, id_name, input_dict), constraints=None, niter=1, bound=bnds)))


print "Time elapsed: ", ti.time() - start_time, "s"
job_server.print_stats()
```

So, it is running the initial iterations, however, it throws the following error :

```
[Error Message, after some iteration are done][1]

chi square error - 1.4150205992
chi square error - 1.4150206112
chi square error - 1.41502057127
chi square error - 1.41502059919
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "carlos_test.py", line 218, in <module>
new_data_set, id_name, input_dict), constraints=None, niter=1, bound=bnds)))
  File "/Users/bhavyabhushan/virtualenvs/elf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pp.py", line 460, in submit
sfunc = self.__dumpsfunc((func, ) + depfuncs, modules)
  File "/Users/bhavyabhushan/virtualenvs/elf/lib/python2.7/site     packages/pp.py", line 636, in __dumpsfunc
   hashs = hash(funcs + modules)
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'OptimizeResult'
```